# Are supersingular K3 surfaces unirational?

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, finite-fields, k3-surfaces

There is a conjecture due to Artin, Rudakov, Shafarevich, Shioda that supersingular K3 surfaces over a finite field are unirational. This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5623.pdf) claims to prove this result but it has had a recent correction [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-020-01028-8) and if I am understanding it right, the mistake is severe enough that the conjecture about unirationality is still open.

Is this correct and have there been other papers addressing this question recently?

Comment: There are some papers of Daniel Bragg and Max Lieblich (search arXiv) on this and related topics but I think the conjecture is still open.

Comment: Thank you! The Bragg-Lieblich paper seems definitive.